# Points in region search

Tags: c++, multithreading, algorithm, search

I have a problem close to [Nearest neighbour search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbour_search), but not exactly.

For a given rectangle region (aligned with axises) in 2D space I need to find all points, which belong to the region.
I can prepare any data about my points set in advance. I have a limits on points coordinates (let's say all points we have are in region from 0 to 1 in both X and Y coordinates).

Number of queries (regions) >> number of points. Therefore my priorities are:

1. QueryTime        - Time to get points by region.
2. MemorySize       - Additional memory size I would need (for preparation).
3. PreparationTime  - Additional data preparation time.

**Which algorithms are appropriate here?** (I would be glad for some books or articles on the topic).

---

Example:

I have an array of points coordinates, all in range from 0 to 1:

{0.1224,0.2345}, {0.01,0.99}, {0.94,0.5}

and get a query to find all points in region from 0.1 to 0.2 in X and from 0.2 to 0.4 in Y.

Then I need to find very first point {0.1224,0.2345}.

Comment: Is the rectangles aligned with the axes?

Comment: I am not sure what exactly are you after. Can you give an example for input for preparation + input for query + expected result please?

Comment: I am looking for other people algorithms and literature..

Comment: @amit, I Will give an examples in 1 minutes

Comment: @amit, see the addition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you have some race condition. It's not clear exactly how you do it.
The usual way is to have the preparation singlethreaded, freeze the structure (pass it as const everywhere) and then all queries can run in parallel with no coordination because the structure is immutable.

Another way is to to a KD-tree or a Quad tree. You'll likely run int the same race issues you're seeing now. 
But in case you want to try it out, use random points, or if you can afford pick the optimal points for the splits (but shouldn't matter a lot in practice).
You'll have something along the lines of O(logNP + R) where R is the number of points in the result.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kd_tree
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree

Answer (score 1):

Sort the points according to x axis and y axis separately.

Get the subset of x and y that match the limits in the corresponding axis.

Pick the one that has fewer elements in the range. For all the elements in the range, pick the the ones that fall within limits of the other axis.

Preparation time nlogn.

Search time: Worst case n, but in practice much less than that.

Additionally you can make search time (logn)^2 or logn depending on how much memory you can have.

If you have O(n^2) memory, you can sort the numbers in every range of x values according to y values. When you are doing the search, you have to find the range on x first and do a search on the sorted list corresponding to that range.

Alternatively, you can sort non overlapping ranges of lengths 2, 4, 8.. etc on the x-axis sorted list. When you get a x range, you have to search within the mini-sorted ranges (there are, worst case, logn ranges) that together make up the range (each search takes at most logn time). Effectively search time is (logn)^2.

Comment: "Sort the points according to x axis and y axis separately"? What does it mean? x and y are of floating points type.

Comment: @klm123 That means maintain two sorted lists: one according to x axis and another according to y axis.

Comment: Ok. I got it. Thanks for idea. Though I afraid it is too slow. +1

Comment: @klm123 I have edited my solution into a more efficient. See if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As @Sorin suggested, you better use geometric trees like KD-tree or R-tree. After your structure is prepared it remains constant and you can query it in parallel from different threads (of course, I assume, the structure is implemented in such a way it does not change its state during the query).

Many libraries provide such data, e.g. Boost.Geometry has rtree and OpenCV has KDtree, see details in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402014/kdtree-implementation-c.

As for data preparation, the typical approach is recursive and fits well with tree construction: split your data into two halves (say, those with X coord above some pivot and those below), build a tree for each part recursively, merge).

The recursive calls can be assigned to separate threads. In fact,  fits perfectly with `tbb::parallel_reduce` and similar parallel patterns. When answering the question, I found some [papers](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/parkd-parallel-k-d-tree-construction-in/227500206) which follows this plan word-to-word.

Comment: My amount of data is about 12MB per one core. But the question is not about parallelisation, but algorithms.